# doctrine2 inner join data in object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

So I am doing two inner joins:

```
<?php

$q->select('o, pic.path pic1, pic_.path pic2');


$q->innerJoin('\TestBundle\Entity\UserImages', 'pic', 'WITH', 'o.id = pic.user');
$q->where('pic.keyname = \'pic1\'');

$q->innerJoin('\TestBundle\Entity\UserImages', 'pic_', 'WITH', 'o.id = pic.user');
$q->where('pic_.keyname = \'pic2\'');
```

This works but the returned result is this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(TestBundle\Entity\user)[1359]
          private 'name' => string 'test' (length=12)
          private 'created' => 
            object(DateTime)[1347]
              ...
          private 'modified' => null
          private 'deleted' => null
          private 'id' => int 1

      'pic1' => string 'pic1.png' (length=8)
      'pic2' => string 'pic2.png' (length=8)
```

Is there any way to have the pic1 and pic2 be set in the object?
I tried adding setPic1/Pic2 to the Users entity but that didn't work.

What do I have to do to get this to work in the result of the query?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `o` table? How are these entities related?

Comment: @A.L 1 to N relationship, but I have updated my question with the solution I found. o table would be the users table (DQL)

Comment: You should be able to add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do what I wanted using just doctrine  but since I am using sonota and this is the reason I needed the pic1 and pic2 I created a **DataGrid Decorator** and intercepted the getResult() method.
In the admin class I override the buildDataGrid (don't have the source code now but I think that was the method) and it will create the datagrid but then I will do something like:

```
$this->datagrid = new DataGridDecorator($this->datagrid)
```

The decorator will then change the result given by the method getResult() to what sonata expects and so I don't have to override I don't know how many templates.

Thanks for the help!